# Proof that the best linear approximation to $f(x)$ near $a$ is given by the linear function $L_{a}(x) = f(a) + f '(a)(x-a)$

Tags: approximation-theory, linear-approximation

The title basically says everything. The formula for linear approximation appears to be right intuitively but is there a proof for it?

Secondly, is there also a proof why to put the $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the second derivative in the quadratic approximation? $$Q_{a}(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}$$

Comment: McLaurin expansion, may be.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think you mean Taylor expansion, as $a$ is not necessarily equal to zero.

Comment: @AlexSchiff. You are perfectly right ! I fact (probably because of my age), I never remember that since, for me, it is just the same ! Thanks for pointing my stupidity. Cheers :-(

Answer (score 2):

We can use a Taylor expansion:

If a function $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2 + ... + \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n + ...$$

If $O((x-a)^n)$ for some $n$ is "small enough", then it is sufficient to use the terms before that for our approximation. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since by definition
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a),$$
we have
$$f(x) = f(a) + (x - a)f'(a) + o(x - a)$$
as $x \to a$. Any other approximation $f(x) = f(a) + C(x - a)$ with $C\not = f'(a)$ would behave like $(C - f'(a))(x - a)$ (which is not $o(x - a)$) near $a$. Alternatively, look at the Taylor series of $f$ at $a$, assuming $f$ has one.

For the second part: Without going through the derivation of the Taylor series, the easiest way to show that the coefficient should be $\frac{1}{2}$ and not $1$ is to take $f(x) = (x - a)^2$.

Comment: "Any other approximation $f(x) = f(a) + C(x - a)$ with $C\not = f'(a)$ would behave like $(C - f'(a))(x - a)$ (which is not $o(x - a)$) near $a$."

What does $o(x-a)$ mean and why is it in the formula below "we have"? If I set $C=f'(a)$ then $(C-f'(a))(x-a)$ is $0$. So, is $o(x-a)$ $0$?

Comment: That's part of [Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). (The definition is given in the "Family of Bachmann–Landau notations" section.)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the following: "Any other approximation $f(x) = f(a) + C(x - a)$ with $C\not = f'(a)$ would behave like $(C - f'(a))(x - a)$ (which is not $o(x - a)$) near $a$." So, if $C=f'(a)$ then $C-f'(a)=0$ and $o(x-a)=0$. Is this true? And, if $o(x-a)$ is zero near a it does not matter. So the rest without $o(x-a)$ is the best  linear approximation since the Taylor series is the best polynomial approximation of $f(x)$. Is this conclusion true? A short feedback would be a great help!

Comment: Without the Big-O notation: Put $L_C(x) = f(x) - f(a) - C(x - a)$ for a fixed constant $C$. For $C = f'(a)$, the function $L_C(x)$ decays at least quadratically in $x - a$ as $x\to a$. For other choices of $C$, the function $L_C(x)$ only decays linearly: it looks like $(C - f'(a))(x - a)$ near $x = a$.